# Graph with 7 vertices and 11 edges and its vertices can be divided into two sets in such a way that no edge joins two vertices in the same set.

Tags: graph-theory

Question:
The graph has 7 vertices and 11 edges and its vertices can be divided into two sets in such a way that no edge joins two vertices in the same set.

How do I know if this graph exist or not. If yes how do i draw it out, if no why?

Comment: Is the graph simple?

Comment: Hint: why don't you try drawing a few of these graphs and see if it works? For drawing, it's easiest if you draw the two sets as two lines, one on the left and one on the right.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** If the $7$ vertices are divided into two sets of size $a$ and $b$, then there are at most $a\cdot b$ edges between them. So then $a\cdot b\geq11$ and $a+b=7$. Now see if you can draw such a graph.

Answer (score 0):

Note that this is a [bipartite graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph) $G=(V,E)$. You can find a partition of $V$ into two subsets $V_1,V_2\subset V$, such that $u,w\in V_1\implies \{u,w\}\not\in E$ and similarly $u,w\in V_2\implies \{u,w\}\not\in E$. Now we see that $\sum_{v_i\in V_j}d(v_i)=11$ for $j=1,2$. This is impossible if $|V_1|=1,2$.

Therefore, without loss of generality, we may assume $|V_1|=3$. Let $V_1=\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ and $V_2=\{v_4,v_5,v_6,v_7\}$. Then let $G'=(V,E')=K_{3,4}$ and let $E=E'\setminus\{v_3,v_7\}$. Here $K_{n,m}$ denotes a [complete bipartite graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_bipartite_graph) with $V=V_1\cup V_2$, $V_1\cap V_2=\varnothing$, and $|V_1|=n$, $|V_2|=m$.